# Is it possible to grant access only to a specific topic on Azure Event Grid Domain (by providing role-based access or somehow else)

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

I am trying to manage access to EventGrid Domain, so only specific users can publish to a specified EventGrid Domain Topic.

Is it possible to do this somehow?

I have tried to create a custom role and specify an assignable scope to the domain topic, but got a validation error:
[Example of creating an assignable scope specifying a domain topic in a scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8cvq.png)

Thank you for any help or suggestions!